# use 1 template for all json response in symfony2

Tags: json, templates, symfony

As I known, each controller must have itself template for json response, how can I force all json response use the same template?

In simple terms, my cotronller/router looks like this:

```
_myname:
    pattern: /xxx/yyy.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: bundle:class:myname, _format:html }
    requirements:{ _format: html|json }


/**
* @Template()
*/
public function mynameAction(){
    return array("data"=>array("error"=>1, "msg"=>"msg"))
}
```

ok, now it works well, when user request /xxx/yyy.html, the controller will render view "myname.html.twig", when user request /xxx/yyy.json, view "myname.json.twig" will show, but, actually every json tempalte are same, how can I let symfony2 know that:

when user request /xxx/yyy.html, render the "myname.html.twig" as normal 
when user request /xxx/yyy.json, **render other template like "default.json.twig" instead of "myname.json.twig"**??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, we have Twig. With twig we can extends some templates. You could create a base json file like this:

```
/Symfony/app/Resources/views/base.json
{
    "success": {% block success %}true{% endblock %},
    "user": {% block user %}guest{% endblock %},
    "items": {% block items %}[]{% endblock %}
}
```

And in all your bundle, you can define any template as extension of base.json

```
{% extends '::base.json' %}

{% block success %}{{ success }}{% endblock %}
{% block user %}app.user{% endblock %}
{% block items %}['one','two','three']{% endblock %}
```

You can also create a sort of factory class. This class can always return a json file in a particulare json structure. And you could not use templates but just return "new Response(json_encode(...))" in your action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have to create a json twig for each action even though they can extends from base template? that's what i try to avoid, i want action just return an array, then framework render html or json template depends on user request, i create html template individually, but want all json request rendered as same template elegantly, without repetitive work.

Comment: Why you have to create a json twig? Symfony2 need a "Response". If you want you can also end your actions with "return new Response(json_encode(array('bla'=>'bla','or'=>123)));"

Comment: if i return a encoded json string instead of an array, the html page will not work. **i need an action render 2 views**, 1 is html page, 1 is json, just depends on the reuqest is /xxx.json or /xxx.html.